# How to use django UserCreationForm correctly

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms

I am new to Django and am just starting my first website. I am trying to set registration for new users.

I used the built in view for login and logout but there is none for registration, in the doc, it says that I should use built in form : UserCreationForm.

The code of my view is :

```
def register(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], None, form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.save()
        return render_to_response('QCM/index.html') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = UserCreationForm() # An unbound form

return render_to_response('register.html', {
    'form': form,
},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It works fine but I am not satisfied as this code is written in the views.py that handles the core of my application (multiple choice question).

My questions are :

- Is this the correct way of using the UserCreationForm
- Where could I put this code so it would be separated from the rest of
  my app

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Django is modular, so you can write a separate *accounts* or *user management* app that can handle user creation, management.
   In that case, you put the code for `register` in the `views.py` of *accounts* app.
2. You can directly save the `UserCreationForm` which will give you user object.

example:

```
...
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
   user = form.save()
...
```